# Не передается $_POST

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ооп

имеется список разделов с чекбоксами и кнопки со значениями(`start`, `stop` и т.д.), проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит, если убрать `$this->model->start($_POST['id']);`, то сообщение о удачи выводится => с ajax всё хорошо.

**Если передать и принять $_POST, то идёт ошибка: Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST**

**Kонтроллер:**

```
public function infoAction() {
    if(!empty($_POST)) {
        $this->model->start($_POST['id']); 
        $this->view->message('succes', 'ok'); // Сообщение о удачи
    } 
    $result = $this->model->selectInfo(); // Вывод данных
    $vars = [
        'data' => $result,
    ];
    
    $this->view->render('Test', $vars); 
}
```

**Mодель:**

```
 public function start($post) {
    $params = [
        'id' => $_POST['id'],
        'command' => $_POST['command'],

    ];
    $this->db->query('UPDATE sections SET command = :command WHERE id = :id', $params);
    
}
```

**Форма:**

```
<form action="/miners/miner" method="POST">
      <div class="button">
        <input type="submit" class="but btn-reset" name="str" value="start">
        <input type="submit" class="but btn-reset" name="stp" value="stop">
        <input type="submit" class="but btn-reset" name="res" value="restart">
        <input type="submit" class="but btn-reset" name="reb" value="reboot">
        <input type="submit" class="but btn-reset" name="add" value="add/change">
        <input type="submit" class="but btn-reset" name="fil" value="filter">
      </div>

  
<?php foreach ($data as $val): ?>
  <div class="miners_container">
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="<? echo $val['id']; ?>" checked>
    <div class="func"><a href="/miners/asic/<? echo $val['owner']; ?>"><? echo $val['name'] ?></a></div>
</div>
</form>
```

`id` в значение чекбокса выводится, может быть `POST` данные в `id` не передаются? И так же хотелось заметить что, это привязано на все кнопки, как можно разграничить на каждую?

**Думал такой проверкой:**

```
if(!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
        $this->model->start($_POST['id']);
        $this->view->message('succes', 'ok');
    }
```

Но не выходит, буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: В `start($post)` передаешь `$_POST['id']` и там же берешь еще раз `$post['id']`. Т.е. пытаешься взять два раза значение id

Comment: Такая проверка не пройдет, нужно смотреть по name полей: $_POST['str'], $_POST['stp'], $_POST['res'] и т.д.

Comment: А если я в start передам $_POST или приму его в модели, то выходит Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST,или я неправильно понял? совсем недавно в ООП просто

Comment: `$this->model->start($_POST);`  - так?

Comment: @Коля Васильев, да, а в модели ничего не менял

Comment: Вы id передаёте, а где command (`SET command = :command`)?

Comment: Пока ничего не понятно, но ошибка о том, что ты где-то пытаешься перезаписать или дать значение переменной `$_POST`

Comment: @InDevX, точно, не доглядел, но эффекта 0. модель : public function start($post) {
  $params = [
   'id' => $post['id'],
            'command' => $post['submit']
  ];
  $this->db->query('UPDATE sections SET command = :command WHERE id = :id', $params);
  
 }

Comment: @ЛысенкоВладимир скиньте полностью текст ошибки (добавьте его в вопрос)

Comment: @InDevX, поправил

Comment: @ЛысенкоВладимир Смотри комментарий, который написал выше, ты не получишь инфы по `$post['submit']`, нужно по значениям name, примеры, `$_POST['str'], $_POST['stp'], $_POST['res']`

Comment: Точно.. Вспомнил.. С php 5.3 или 5.4 (точно не помню) и выше нельзя $_POST передавать аргументом... Можете формировать массив данных, и передавать уже сами параметры для запроса, или передавайте 2 аргумента - `...start($_POST['id'], $_POST['command'])`

Comment: @InDevX, Спасибо попробую, с вами можно где то связаться, что бы удобнее было?

Comment: @inDevX, пользователь не найден